# Windows 7: Creating shortcuts to folders and pinning them

Tags: windows-7, desktop, shortcuts

I need a system for having instant access to particular directories while not taking up too much screen space (ie: IMO, object dock is too obtrusive). At this point I am making short cuts to various "most used" folders onto my desktop... I need a better system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **Windows 7**, it's really easy to quickly access your folders without installing any applications. First of all, make sure that you have **Windows Explorer pinned to the taskbar** (it is there by default).

If it is there, open it and **navigate to the folder** you want to access with ease. Select the folder and simply **drag-and-drop it's icon onto the Windows Explorer icon** in the taskbar.

After you pinned all the folders you need, you can quickly access them by **right-clicking on the icon** of Windows Explorer on the taskbar. You will see the folders under the *'Pinned'* section on the top. You can rearrange these by drag-and-drop.

See images here: [IMAGES](http://zqqv7q.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pXePlCYz8G4ZdXYIhtzVDElLC1lKyIP5AFnrnpJjyhUlskYuWw6oFoy_bBxVCsGJv7piNuuVxOhZCr_5sXwNC7wADoDVm_HsM/superuser_1.jpg)

Comment: Now that I think about it, this is the best solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas from lifehacker:

[medalfolders](http://lifehacker.com/5362932/medalfolders-makes-accessing-favorite-folders-quick-and-easy) puts all your favorite locations two clicks away in the system tray.

[folder-guide](http://lifehacker.com/5041428/folder-guide-adds-quick-folder-access-to-your-right+click-menu) adds user-defined folders to your right-click menu for quick, easy access to any number of favorite folders.

[direct-folders](http://lifehacker.com/373040/add-quick-access-to-your-filesystem-with-direct-folders) jumps quickly to any folder on your filesystem .

[folder-menu](http://lifehacker.com/5301498/folder-menu-is-a-powerful-folder-switching-tool) adds quick access to your favorite applications and folders through a popup navigation menu—and it even works in those irritating File Open dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **[Anvir Task Manager Free](http://download.cnet.com/AnVir-Task-Manager-Free/3000-2086_4-10802050.html)**. Among tons of other useful features, you can access your favorite (Add Folder To This List) and most recent locations from the system tray:

[image]

A [portable version](http://www.anvir.com/download.htm) is also available.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.unawave.de/windows-7-tipps/folder-to-taskbar.html?lang=EN) is a nice trick to pin individual folders to the taskbar in Windows 7.

Basically you create an empty `.txt` file, the rename it to `.exe`. Right click it and select "Pin to taskbar".

Once it's done right click the new "pin" and change the shortcut to the folder that you wish.